# VSTO Outlook add in. Get moderator accounts of moderated Exchange distribution list

Tags: outlook, vsto, exchange-server, outlook-addin, mapi

VSTO Outlook addin question.

I got moderated Exchange distribution list and need to know which members of this list are moderators.
To know if list is moderated I use [PidTagAddressBookModerationEnabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee204552(v=exchg.80).aspx) MAPI property(it works):

```
    var isModerated = MapiHelper.GetProperty(addressEntry, 
MapiProperty.PidTagAddressBookModerationEnabled);
```

I have all members of the this list as `Outlook.Recipient` class members. What I tried so far, just to get at least some information :

```
foreach (Outlook.Recipient recipient in mailItem.Recipients)
       {
          var try1 = MapiHelper.GetProperty(recipient, MapiProperty.PidTagAddressBookAuthorizedSenders);
          var try2 = MapiHelper.GetProperty(recipient, MapiProperty.PidTagAddressBookDistributionListMemberSubmitAccepted);
       }
```

Both try1 and try2 are `null` even when recipient is moderator account. Also I did not find anything relevant to finding moderation accounts in MAPI properties. Is there other way, did I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see anything else besides PR_EMS_AB_ENABLE_MODERATION for the DL in OutlookSpy or MFCMAPI?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko,  in OutlookSpy I have GetRecipientTable in IMessage where I can see DL properties - there is even no ENABLE_MODERATION. Could you advice where else or how in Outlook Spy must I search?

Comment: You need to open the corresponding IDistList object - double click on the row in the GetRecipientTable in IMessage.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko, I did like you said and found in GetContentsTable lots of MAPI properties without values. As I suspect not all of them can be applied to distribution lists. For example I found PR_EMS_AB_ADMIN_DISPLAY_NAME. It may or may not be connected with DL admins. Is there any documentation for those properties? I looked in Internet and did not find anything

Comment: Some are documented, most are not :-)